# How to move points of a CGPathRef

Tags: objective-c, cgpath

I am making a game where the player can draw a line with their finger, except I would like to show movement in the game. I have it so that when the player moves their finger it draws as if you were drawing on a piece of paper. However I want it to act more as if you were walking down a sidewalk and drawing side to side on it with a piece of chalk while moving. As the game goes on I would like the rest of the line to trail to the bottom of the screen while drawing. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a stranger to build the entire game for you, doesn't it?

Comment: @ElTomato this is only a small part of the entire game, I would really appreciate some help